# Euclidean algorithm in integer quaternion ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to compute right gcd on integer quaternions. Similary to division with remainder in Gauss integers, i compute remainder as $r = a - [\frac{a*\overline{b}}{b*\overline{b}}]*b$ (where a supposed to be divided on b). Sometimes it works, however happens that $[\frac{a*\overline{b}}{b*\overline{b}}]$ equals to zero, hence remainder has bigger norm than quaternion to be divided. As [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion) says, to overcome this problem we should shift to quaternions with half integer coefficients, however i don't understand how to deal with them. Am i supposed to multiply both sides of equality by $\frac{1}{2}(1+i+j+k)$, when trouble like this happens, and then deal with them like fractions ?

Comment: See [here](https://mavdisk.mnsu.edu/pj2943kt/Fall%202014/Math%20492%20Fall%202014/Hurwitz%20Numbers%20and%20the%20Four%20Squares%20Theorem.pdf) page 2 in particular when they consider the case of failure.